# Put multiple elements to JavaScript Array

Tags: javascript

In ***JavaScript*** I am filling ***array*** elements by traditional way, such as:

```
myArray[12] = 123;
myArray[13] = 432;
myArray[14] = 233;
myArray[15] = 98;
```

Is it possible to do this faster by one command?

For example to put numbers `[123, 432, 233, 98]` to `myArray[12-15]` ... somehow? Not one by one.

---

And how can be optimized this kind of scenario:

```
newArray[12] = oldArray[30];
newArray[13] = oldArray[31];
newArray[14] = oldArray[32];
newArray[15] = oldArray[33];
```

when n elements (4 in the above example) next each to other from one array need to be moved to another array?

Please advice.

Comment: Where are the values coming from?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
var myArray = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 
               12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20];
myArray.splice(12, 4, 123, 432, 233, 98);

// [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 
//  123, 432, 233, 98, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
```

The first parameter to `splice` is the index to start with, the second is the number of elements to remove, the remainder are elements to insert.  So if you insert the same number as were removed, you end up replacing them.

If you do want this to come from another array, you could try this, although it is not as clean:

```
var oldArray = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11,
               12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21,
               22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 123, 
               432, 233, 98, 34, 35]
var newArray = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 
               12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20];

[].splice.apply(newArray, [12, 4].concat(oldArray.slice(30, 30 + 4)));

// [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11,
// 123, 432, 233, 98, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
```

This is probably less efficient than [PointedEars suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11368883) but it's quite simple and would probably serve for many use cases.

Answer (score 4):

The closest you can come is to use `splice` to set the input position.

The first argument is the index to at which to begin, the second argument is how many items to remove, and the next arguments are the values....

Here is some output I get messing around in a console.

```
myArray = new Array(15)
myArray.splice(12, 4, 123, 432, 223, 98)
myArray.forEach(function(v, i){console.log(v, i)})
123 12
432 13
223 14
98 15
undefined
myArray[12]
123
myArray[13]
432
myArray[14]
223
myArray[15]
98
```

Of course this has several deficiencies: you can't pass an array of values you want to insert, the array needs to be large enough (i.e you cant insert at index 12 unless the array is at least 12 long).

For transferring values at one set of indexes in one array to another set of indexes in another array, I think you have to loop.  `splice` takes the values to add individually, not as an array.  You could of course write a single method with the loop, and reuse it.

Comment: Good idea, but `Array.prototype.splice()` will *insert* the elements, *not* replace existing ones. To work around that, you will have to remove as many elements as you are inserting. I think the best solution here is to use a loop, but it would be nice if ECMAScript implementations would support slice-replace as Python does. Maybe in Harmony (ES 6).

Comment: just did, you are SOL, you have to loop.

Comment: SOL = Sht out of luck.  As in, "you can't do it without looping, you are SOL, sorry"

Comment: I see. However, you *can* do it without a loop: `var items = [123, 432, 223, 98]; myArray.splice.apply(myArray, [12, items.length].concat(items));`. The question is, *would you want to?* It is more than twice as expensive than the ordinary, perhaps generalized, loop. And I am not even talking about memory here. See also my answer.

Answer (score 4):

**Latest Method: Use Spread with Splice**

Here is the latest and easiest way to do this.

Use `...` (spread) operator along with `splice` method used in previous examples.

This removes 4 elements starting from index 12 and then inserts your required array into positions 12 to 15.

**Try Sample Code**

```js
const myArray = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 
               12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20];

console.log('Before:', JSON.stringify(myArray));

myArray.splice(12, 4, ...[123, 432, 233, 98]);

console.log('After: ', JSON.stringify(myArray));
```

Further Reference: ECMAScript (ECMA-262)

Comment: An interesting drawback of any approach with spread function params involves unexpected stack-overflow errors - this is because javascript passes argument via the stack. For `arr.splice(1, 2, ...[ /* a million items */ ])` you will encounter stack-overflow issues.

Answer (score 2):

`Array.prototype.push()` and `Array.prototype.splice()` are nice ideas, but `push()` always appends to the end of the array (that is, starting from the index specified by the `length` property), and `splice()` requires you to remove as many elements as you are inserting before you are inserting (which is *twice as expensive* as it needs to be).

Therefore, you should use a loop:

```
 for (var i = 12; i < 16; ++i)
 {
   _new[i] = old[i + 18];
 }
```

(`new` is a keyword, thus reserved; your example code is not executable.  I have used `_new` here to work around that.)

This can be generalized:

```
function putValues(array1, array2, start1, start2, num)
{
  if (typeof start1 == "undefined") start1 = 0;
  if (typeof start2 == "undefined") start2 = 0;
  var max = (typeof num == "undefined") ? array2.length : start2 + num;

  for (var i = start1, j = start2; j < max; ++i, ++j)
  {
    array1[i] = array2[j];
  }
}

putValues(newArray, oldArray, 12, 30, 4);
```

More sophisticated generalizations are conceivable, such as passing one or two arrays of indexes, so that the indexes do not have to be successive.

(Resist the temptation to make this a method of `Array.prototype`, unless you want to have to use `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty()` when iterating efficiently with `for`-`in` in an unordered fashion over sparse arrays.)

Next time, try *something* first.

Comment: `splice` does not require you to remove any particular number of elements.  If you want to replace a certain set of them in this manner, you should remove that number.  But that doesn't seem much of a limitation.

Comment: @ScottSauyet Read the question again.

Comment: And thanks for the downvotes. Just because you do not understand or like an answer it does not mean it is wrong or not useful.

Comment: I reread the question and saw "Is it possible to do this faster by one command?".  When I saw your, probably efficient, but far from succinct code, I down-voted.  That was hasty, though, and I removed it.

Comment: Also, I don't believe the addition of the source of the old data was in the question when I answered it.  (I may be wrong about it.)  But the basic question is quite simple, and answered quite simply.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `push` function:

```
myarray.push([123, 432, 233, 98]);
```

to add whole array to your array or to add individual items:

```
myarray.push(123, 432, 233, 98);
```

To add to **specific location**, you would need to use `splice()` function.

**Docs:**

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

Comment: @Blaster Pushing an array onto an array isn't going to do what you expect

Comment: @Ωmega: I have also added `splice` function which allows you to put items at specified position.

Answer (score 1):

You should use .concat(), as follows:

```
myArray = myArray.concat([123, 432, 233, 98])
```

Or use .push() as follows:

```
myArray.push(123,432,233,98)
```